# How do I get Authentication with rsocket and JWT?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux, rsocket

### Issues

I'm trying to make a chat application with RSocket-java and I want to save Authentication in ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.

When I get Context from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder, it always says 'empty'.
But if I debug BearerPayloadExchangeConverter parse token to Authentication well and ReactiveSecurityContextHolder has the Authentication.

I can't find my problem.

### My SecurityConfig

```
@Bean
public PayloadExchangeAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter() {
    return new BearerPayloadExchangeConverter();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), MacAlgorithm.HS256.getName());

    return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey)
            .macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder) {
    JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager = new JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(reactiveJwtDecoder);

    JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(authenticationConverter));
    return jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager;
}

@Bean
PayloadSocketAcceptorInterceptor authorization(RSocketSecurity security) {
    return security.authorizePayload(authorize ->
                    authorize
                            .setup().permitAll()
                            .anyExchange().authenticated())
            .jwt(jwt -> {
                try {
                    jwt.authenticationManager(jwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(reactiveJwtDecoder()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).build();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveUserDetailsService reactiveUserDetailsService() {
    return username -> userAdapter.getUserInfo(username)
            .map(AuthDetails::new);
}
```

### Result of Debug

My biggest problem is ReactiveSecurityContextHolder send SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY as reactor.onDiscard.local

[ReactiveSecurityContextHolder debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZEzI.png)

[My github link](https://github.com/jhhong0509/rsocket-chatting-example/tree/main/chatting)

Please let me know the solution. thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are registering two authenticationManagers… you are both registering it manually, and creating a @bean in the context. Either you use @bean or you set it manually. Dont do both. I recommend removing the entire `try { jwt.authenticationManager } catch { … }` i cant tell if this is your problem but that is one thing that might cause it.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

I tried as you told me. But It does not work.
I deleted @Bean annotation from AuthenticationManager and I called JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager from PayloadSocketAcceptorIntercepter.
I'd try to delete try-catch but if I delete it, AuthenticationManager does not work...

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I failed to use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.
Instead of that, I used `@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "getClaims().get('sub')")` to get authentication's subject.
If you have any other way, please comment